# Adobe Air sockets and SSL

Tags: javascript, sockets, ssl, air

I'm writing an Air application which uses sockets. I need to connect to nexus.passport.com:443 using SSL. Is this possible? If so, how?

I use JavaScript for the programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adobe AIR 2.0 has added securesockets:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/reference/html/flash/net/SecureSocket.html

Answer (score 2):

According to [this article](http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/communityengine/index.cfm?event=showdetails&productId=4&postId=10567) on Adobe's site, you can't currently do this with sockets, but rather must use the URLRequest API.

> The only current limitation is that
>   there is not currently an SSL Socket
>   implementation in AIR. For secure
>   communication with a server you will
>   be limited to HTTPS using the
>   URLRequest API.